# Typescript error when using require - This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import(...)' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-fetch

I'm trying to run this script

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function test() {
  fetch('https://google.com')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
}

test();
```

But i get this error

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'typeof import("(...)/node_modules/node-fetch/@types/index")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

although it works when i use import

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

why and how to fix it?

Comment: Most likely the default export is on the `default` prop of the module. How `const {default as fetch} = require('node-fetch')` resolve?

Comment: Sorry, i tried const { fetch as fetch } = require('node-fetch');  but i got 'Module '"node-fetch"' has no exported member 'fetch'. Did you mean to use 'import fetch from "node-fetch"' instead?ts(2614)'

Comment: Also the npm page mentions: 'node-fetch is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require.' i'm still trying to do it, because my file has also require to load json. How would you solve this? make everything import?

Comment: Why using `require` if you can use `import`? I also suppose you can `import` jsons, but if it fails, you can use `import` for modules and `require()` for json files

Comment: @ObaApi You said "I tried const { fetch as fetch } = require('node-fetch');". That's not what I wrote. Specifically, how does `const {default as fetch} = require('node-fetch')` work out for you?

Comment: Thanks, i'm getting this error:
   ':' expected.ts(1005)
Duplicate identifier 'as'.ts(2300)

Comment: @ObaApi Oops. Sorry, I got confused with `import` syntax. I meant `const {default : fetch} = require('node-fetch')`

Comment: Actually const {default as fetch} = require('node-fetch') also works. I still try to find a way to load json credentials in an easy way in a module file that does not allow require. I've made  new post for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014923/is-there-an-easy-way-to-load-json-in-a-node-module

Comment: @spender that worked for me and axios, so I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 7):

As per [spender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012702/typescript-error-when-using-require-this-expression-is-not-callable-type-typ#comment121973608_69012702), you can change the require to use this destructuring:

```
const {default : fetch} = require('node-fetch');
```

This has worked for me in a similar situation (using axios in node, which has a similar API)