# Is there an easy way to load json in a node module?

Tags: node.js, json

Before you read my adventure below, i'm looking for a **simple** way to load json credentials in a module. My adventure took many steps, so I assume there is a quicker way!

I try to import modules and load a json.
I started with a require:

```
import { default as fetch } from 'node-fetch';
import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet';
let creds = require('./credentials/sheets123456123456.json');
```

I get this error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use
> import instead This file is being treated as an ES module because it
> has a '.js' file extension and
> '/Users/wimdenherder/Documents/Programmeren/Nodejs/Sellvation/programmeren/fetch/package.json'
> contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it
> to use the '.cjs' file extension.

I tried to rewrite to imports proposed by Stefan Judis in this [article](https://www.stefanjudis.com/snippets/how-to-import-json-files-in-es-modules-node-js/)

```
import { default as fetch } from 'node-fetch';
// import { default as creds } from './credentials/sheets2569224e80ce5d0c2d.json';
import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet';
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const creds = require('./credentials/sheets123456123456.json');
```

But then tslint gives an error:

> The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'esnext', or 'system'.ts(1343)

I have to updates tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext"
```

but the folder does not have a tsconfig.json, so i run

```
tsc --init
```

but ironically tslint gives an error in the tsconfig.json file!

> No inputs were found in config file

so i create an empty .ts file and restart visual code studio as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211566/tsconfig-json-buildno-inputs-were-found-in-config-file).
Then i run again the script

```
node index.js
```

Then i get this error

> TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json"
> for
> /Users/wimdenherder/Documents/Programmeren/Nodejs/Sellvation/programmeren/fetch/credentials/sheets123456123456.json

which i fix by running the hint from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205891/import-json-extension-in-es6-node-js-throws-an-error)

```
node --experimental-json-modules
```

and now it works!

So my question is, is there an **easier way to load json in modules** in nodejs?

PS: i also got this typescript error

> Cannot find module '/credentials/sheets2569224e80ce5d0c2d.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.

which i solved by updating tslint.config and restarting visual code

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your `tsconfig.json` file by adding the below options.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

After doing above you will be able to import the json file like following:

```
import credentials from "./credentials/sheets123456123456.json";

console.log(credentials);
```

Comment: Looks great, where did you find this? do you recommend certain books, documentation? To avoid adventures like i had above ;)

Comment: When i run tsc-watch i get this error in the created .js file: Property '__importDefault' does not exist on type 'typeof import(".../build/index")'.ts(2339). How can i fix this?